# store images in an array

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to store images(I cropped them in a for loop,after every crop,I want to store in an array) into an array of images. How could I do that in OpenCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<IplImage*> vec_images;

IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); // Acquiring a new image
// Cropping or whatever

vec_images.push_bask(frame);
```

Don't forget to deallocate these frames when you don't need them anymore:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec_images.size(); i++)
  cvReleaseImage(&vec_images[i]);
```

Comment: How to do the same but with cv::Mat instead of IplImage* ?

Comment: Same stuff, except the release part which you need to call the `release()` method to release a `cv::Mat`.